# cloudsim spawns high CPU instance (paid) on free EC2 AWS

Tags: drcsim, cloudsim

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I installed cloudsim on AWS EC2 free version micro instance. After some trouble and heartache with the installation, it finally worked. However, when I went to launch a drc simulation instance, it stated that it was spawning a High GPU instance in order to run the simulation. I am fully away aware of the heavy requirements that drcsim needs to perform the rendering and calculations. However, I was surprised that it was allowed to spawn a High CPU instance from within my free EC2. When I contacted AWS, they confirmed that indeed the instance it was spawning to run the simulation is a paid service and somewhat expensive at that. Is there a way to force cloudsim to spawn all its instances using only the free micro version of AWS EC2? Are we expected to pay for the High GPU model in order to run cloudsim? Is there another way for us to run cloudsim?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/1113/cloudsim-spawns-high-cpu-instance-(paid)-on-free-ec2-aws/) by [aqiruse](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/110/aqiruse/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 48 on 2013-01-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Gazebo runs best with a strong cpu/gpu combination, because it generates camera images for the sensors, and performs rigid body dynamics simulation. The market for GPU equipped cloud machines available on demand is very restricted at the moment.

CloudSim is developed in the context of DARPA's Challenge where simulation of complex world and walking robots must be achieved in real time.

For these reasons, CloudSim is designed around these expensive machines... right now.

Running on cheaper machines (or even free ones) is an important long term goal for CloudSim, in scenarios where real time performance is not an issue. Stay tuned.

---

Originally posted by [hugomatic](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/59/hugomatic/) with karma: 116 on 2013-01-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0